# Pandas - Returning single dates for a date range and match weekday binary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### **Dataset:**

Below dataset is supposed to replicate a timetable data set for a travel company (e.g. routes via train or bus or plane etc.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_d', 'op_d'],
                   'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'x'], 
                   'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'y'], 
                   'valid_from': ['13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '20/05/2019', '21/05/2019'],
                   'valid_to': ['20/11/2018', '20/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '30/05/2019', '29/05/2019'], 
                   'day_of_week': ['0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0001101', '1110000', '0000000', '0000001', '1000000', '1000001']})
    print(df)
```

`operator` - operating company e.g. ABC Airlines, DEF Train Company

`from` - departing from e.g. London, New York, Narnia

`to` - destination e.g. Paris

`valid_from` - start of a date range (can be any day of the week) where route is available for purchase for the operator e.g. `2019-11-01`

`valid_to` - end of date range (can be any day of the week) where route is available to purchase for the operator e.g. `2019-11-12`

`day_of_week` - binary representing availability for Sun to Sat e.g. `0101010` means route is available on Mon, Wed, and Fri in the date range

### **Required:**

An output dataset that converts the date range to single individual dates and their availability derived from the `day_of_week` field. The main goal is to get a clean dataset which can then loaded into Tableau to then build a report that would easily show route availability.

### **Desired Output:**

```
dfout = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a'], 'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'date': ['13/11/2018', '14/11/2018', '15/11/2018', '16/11/2018', '17/11/2018', '18/11/2018', '19/11/2018'], 'available': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
print(dfout)
```

So this would be the output for `op_a` for the route `a` to `b` for date range `2018-11-13` to `2018-11-19`.

The dataset is weird as. Date ranges can be quite random, but `day_of_week` will always show availability for the days of the week in that date range. Some of the same date ranges may even have different `day_of_week` binary combinations, but essentially if at any point the `day_of_week` indicates an availability for a given date range, route and operator, then it will be taken to be available for the date.

### **What I've tried to do:**

Using the following for help: [Pandas: decompress date range to individual dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066782/pandas-decompress-date-range-to-individual-dates)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_d', 'op_d'],
                   'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'x'], 
                   'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'y'], 
                   'valid_from': ['13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '20/05/2019', '21/05/2019'],
                   'valid_to': ['20/11/2018', '20/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '30/05/2019', '29/05/2019'], 
                   'day_of_week': ['0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0001101', '1110000', '0000000', '0000001', '1000000', '1000001']})

df.set_index(['operator', 'from','to'], inplace=True)

df['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_from'])
df['valid_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_to'])

df['row'] = range(len(df))
starts = df[['valid_from', 'day_of_week', 'row']].rename(columns={'valid_from': 'date'})
ends = df[['valid_to', 'day_of_week', 'row']].rename(columns={'valid_to':'date'})

df_decomp = pd.concat([starts, ends])
df_decomp = df_decomp.set_index('row', append=True)
df_decomp.sort_index()

df_decomp = df_decomp.groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').fillna(method='pad'))
```

Result looks promising. My final thoughts are to:

1. add a `weekday` column that returns the weekday of the `date` starting with `Sunday` as `0`
2. add an `available` column that returns the binary value in `day_of_week` using `weekday` as the position index
3. lastly, to somehow remove duplicate `operator`,`from` and `to` rows and keeping `available`'s that have `1` and dropping those that are `0` or if there are no `1`'s for those `operators`'/`from`'s/`to`'s then keep the available as `0`...

madness...apologies for the long-windedness and I hope I'm making some sense. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

- Updated the 'What I've tried to do' part above.
- Updated dataset a tad to include a bit more variety in the dates (still the same dataset just adjusted `valid_to` dates)

Comment: Nicely asked question

Comment: --Thanks @JohnH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_d', 'op_d'],
                   'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'x'], 
                   'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'y'], 
                   'valid_from': ['13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '20/05/2019', '21/05/2019'],
                   'valid_to': ['20/11/2018', '20/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/11/2018', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '30/05/2019', '29/05/2019'], 
                   'day_of_week': ['0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0001101', '1110000', '0000000', '0000001', '1000000', '1000001']})

# set operator, from, to as index
df.set_index(['operator', 'from','to'], inplace=True)

# convert date ranges to datetime types
df['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_from'])
df['valid_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_to'])

# bring individual dates in date ranges and stack
df['row'] = range(len(df))
starts = df[['valid_from', 'day_of_week', 'row']].rename(columns={'valid_from': 'date'})
ends = df[['valid_to', 'day_of_week', 'row']].rename(columns={'valid_to':'date'})

df_decomp = pd.concat([starts, ends])
df_decomp = df_decomp.set_index('row', append=True)
df_decomp.sort_index()

df_decomp = df_decomp.groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('D').fillna(method='pad'))

# remove indexes
df_decomp.reset_index(level=3, drop=True, inplace=True)
df_decomp.reset_index(inplace=True)

# create weekday column
df_decomp['weekday'] = np.where(df_decomp['date'].dt.weekday == 6, 
                            df_decomp['date'].dt.weekday - 6, 
                            df_decomp['date'].dt.weekday + 1)

# use weekday to extract availability in day_of_week
df_decomp['available'] = [b[a] for a, b in zip(df_decomp['weekday'], df_decomp['day_of_week'])]
df_decomp['available'] = df_decomp['available'].astype('int')

# sort values and remove duplicates with available=1 taking priority
df_decomp = df_decomp.sort_values('available', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['operator','from','to','date'])
df_decomp = df_decomp.sort_values(['operator','from','to','date'])

df_decomp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about speed, you can use iterrows() and df.at[]:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_b', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_c', 'op_d', 'op_d'], 'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'x'], 'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'y'], 'valid_from': ['13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '13/11/2018', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '15/02/2019', '01/05/2019', '01/05/2019'], 'valid_to': ['19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '19/11/2018', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '10/05/2019', '11/05/2019'], 'day_of_week': ['0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0101010', '0100010', '0111100', '1101100', '0001101', '1110000', '0000000', '0000001', '1000000', '1000001']})

df['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_from'])
df['valid_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_to'])
df['day'] = (df['valid_from']+pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.weekday # gives weekdays : ) = Sunday
print df.head()


df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['available', 'date', 'from', 'operator', 'to'])

idx = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    daterange = row['valid_to'] - row['valid_from']
    print daterange.days

    daystring = 52 * (row['day_of_week'])  # extend string to allow going through multiple weeks

    for j in range(daterange.days+1):
        df_out.at[idx, ['available', 'date', 'from', 'operator', 'to']] = [ # replaced set_value with df.at[]
            int(daystring[j + row['day']]), # use day of the week as starting position
            row['valid_from']+pd.to_timedelta(j, unit='d'),
            row['from'],
            row['operator'],
            row['to']
            ]

        # row['day_of_week'][j]
        idx += 1

df_out.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) # drop all duplicates
df_0 = df_out[df_out['available']==0]
df_1 = df_out[df_out['available']==1]
df_out = df_0.merge(df_1, how='outer', left_on=['date', 'from', 'operator', 'to'], right_on=['date', 'from', 'operator', 'to'])
df_out.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df_out['available'] = df_out['available_x'] + df_out['available_y']
df_out.drop(['available_x', 'available_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_out.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True)
print df_out
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - only thing is that the `day_of_week` starts on Sunday, and the date range could start on e.g. a Tuesday, so I would need the `day_of_week` binary to match the weekday in the date range (if that makes sense?)

Comment: I think (and correct me if I'm wrong) but your `row['day_of_week'][j]` within the `value` param is taking the binary combos from left to right in `day_of_week` and assigning them against each individual single dates within the date range. Is there a way to alter that part to match the `day_of_week` against the weekday within the dates in the daterange?

Comment: you are correct. I changed it such that it takes the actual weekday as starting point. see edited version and comments.

Comment: yes, i think you got it. I had to amend the `df['day'] = df['valid_from'].dt.weekday` part to `df['day'] = np.where(df['valid_from'].dt.weekday == 6,
                     df['valid_from'].dt.weekday - 6,
                     df['valid_from'].dt.weekday + 1)` because pandas has Mon as 0 and the dataset's `day_of_week` has Sun starting at 0. The only things left is to remove duplicates and keep `available` as either a 1 or 0, giving precedence to 1 if it's there for that operator/route/date. And lastly `set_value` is deprecated so would need to get that fixed somehow...

Comment: you're going to hate me for this but I'm still not getting the desired output i.e. for `op_a` the result should be `dfout = pd.DataFrame({'operator': ['op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a', 'op_a'], 'from': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 'to': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'date': ['13/11/2018', '14/11/2018', '15/11/2018', '16/11/2018', '17/11/2018', '18/11/2018', '19/11/2018'], 'available': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})`

Comment: unfortunately my for loop game is weak...but alternatively could we, say we're starting from scratch, stack the individual dates within the date range against operator, route and binary combo and then add another column `available`, to index the binary combo based on the row's weekday? So if we have date `2018-11-13` which is a `Tuesday`, set `weekday` to `2` for that and then index position `[2]` from the `day_of_week` to get the `available`....and then right at the end collect all `available` duplicates for that op/route/date and keep the duplicate with a `1` and drop the duplicate with `0`